# Notification on Firestore Added

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, google-cloud-firestore

I make a project where i can recieve notification when the data added into firestore. Since im still newbie , i dont know how to implement the notification to the added data in firestore. I trying the fcm, but i dont understand how to implement it.

Can anybody tell me How to add the notification? Where should i put ?

Here is my code:

```
Query firstQuery = mFirestore.collection("OnlineBusiness").orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

    firstQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {


            if (e != null) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Error : " + e.getMessage());

            } else {

                for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                    UserSendDetail userSendDetail = doc.getDocument().toObject(UserSendDetail.class);
                    userSendDetailList.add(userSendDetail);
                    userSendDetail.notify();

                    usersListSendDetailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    createNotify();
                }
            }

        }
    });


}


private void createNotify() {

    //AlarmService
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);

    Intent intent = new Intent("my.wedee.com.inilahapps.AlarmReceiver.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
    PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want this to work even when your app is closed I would use FCM and Firebase Cloud Functions to achieve this.

You can fire up a function whenever data changed in firestore:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created

within that function then I would trigger a push notification:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages

And then receive it within Android:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Hope that helps!

Comment: the things is i got server side using apps. so, is this possible if data added from main apps to server side?

Comment: Cloud Functions Firestore triggers will work no matter who or what device added the document.

Comment: Id like to know, if it sends a notification to all devices when new document created?